# Jenkins download file using SCP

Tags: jenkins

I'm new to Jenkins and I can't do what seems to be trivial.

I would like to download a file from a remote server to my Jenkins master server using SCP.

Manually, on the Jenkins server, I can run this command successfully:

```
scp -i /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/private_key jenkins@remoteServer:/home/jenkins/file.txt /tmp/.
# I enter the passphrase and press enter
```

I could find the plugin Publish over SSH, but unfortunately it can only send files.

The remoteServer is not a Jenkins slave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be straightforward; [create a Jenkins job](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project) and add an ["execute shell" step](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-ShellScriptsandWindowsBatchCommands) to run the scp command.  You'll need to specify credentials in Jenkins since the shell step is non-interactive and can't respond to the request for the passphrase. I could't find documentation on credentials setup, but you can reach it at $JENKINS_URL/credential-store.

Comment: thank you. I looked at the documentation and some other plugins, but couldn't find a way to do it when the private key is protected by a passphrase. I will continue to search.